# {"Failed to convert parameter value from a Object[] to a Decimal."} in SqlBulkCopy using SqlParameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, sqlbulkcopy, sqlparameter

I need to insert bulk data into a SQL Server database.

The data is fetched in SqlParameter.

```
foreach (DataColumn c in data.Columns)
{
    SqlDbType dbType = GetSqlDbTypeFromDotnetType(c.DataType);

    var columnDataObject = data.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<object>(c.ColumnName));

    object[] paramDataArray = (UploadEverythingInSingleBatch)
             ? columnDataObject.ToArray()
             : columnDataObject.Skip(skipOffset).Take(batchSize).ToArray();

    SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
    param.SqlDbType = dbType;
    param.Value = paramDataArray;
    parameters.Add(param);
}

SqlCommand cmd = _connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = commandText;

//parameters data replaced
parameters.ForEach(p => cmd.Parameters.Add(p));

int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

// on execution nonquery 
// {"Failed to convert parameter value from a Object[] to a Decimal."}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXYae.png)

Comment: You cannot pass an array as a parameter. You would need a Table Valued Parameter for that, and therefore a table type, which would be difficult to do generically. I suggest you create a custom table type and script for the table you want to upload into. Alternatively just use `SqlBulkCopy`, which is very fast and easy to use (but only works with simple inserts)

Comment: Thank you. Can you please share SqlBulk copy

Comment: Second link above should help you